# Dojo documentation alternative

Tags: javascript, html, dojo, widget

I've been developing dojo widgets lately but I'm still new to dojo so I need a lot of help from the dojo website https://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/ to understand different modules but it's been down for like a week.

Is there other places that documented this api? Thank you.

Comment: Asking for off-site resources is off-topic for Stack Overflow. But when a website is down you can always try to use the [Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20171215051426/https://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/).

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using Dojo 2.0. The website http://dojotoolkit.org is for version 1.0. More information about dojo 2.0 you can find on https://dojo.io/ or GitHub https://github.com/dojo. I would like to notice that dojo 2.0 is on Release Candidate step.