# Why is dojotoolkit.org suspended?

Tags: dojo

When I go to https://dojotoolkit.org/, I get, "Unable to connect".  In some browsers I get "You have reached a domain that is pending ICANN verification".

I've used a number of dojo libraries in my code. Does anyone know what happened to the owner and whether this is likely to be fixed in the near future?

If it isn't fixed, what is my best option for replacing it?

Comment: doc is available right now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The site now appears to be back up. I was able to access it and get information on features I'm using.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a temporary administrative DNS issue, based on their [Twitter response](https://twitter.com/dojo/status/1008720540838842368):

> We apologize for the issues accessing the Dojo 1 web site. We’re
>   working on it as fast as possible. In the mean time, you can add the
>   IP address directly to /etc/hosts. 104.16.205.241

There are also some workarounds on the [dojo gitter.im channel](https://gitter.im/dojo/dojo?at=5b241a151ee2d149ecc5bd01):

> Reference guide content is also at https://github.com/dojo/docs/ And
>   tutorials are at
>   https://github.com/dojo/dojo-website/tree/master/src/documentation/tutorials

Also, as mentioned in this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50908711/2039), you can use the [Archive.org Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20171215051426/https://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/).